# Backbone.xmpp: Fetching subscriptions

Tags: backbone.js, xmpp

How do I use Backbone.xmpp to fetch subscriptions? I know I get them by `XMPPConnection.PubSub.getSubscriptions();` but how do I use Collections, Models and a View for subscriptions? Do I have to use a Backbone.Collection and Backbone.Model because Backbone.xmppSync's Collections and Models are for leaf nodes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://ggozad.com/Backbone.xmpp/), subscriptions are not managed by the nodes directly. The node models provides by Backbone.xmpp merely sync with the XMPP nodes and provide real time notifications.

You have to do it either server-side (preferable as you can impose whatever security workflow you like) or client side by utilising the bundled pubsub plugin for Strophe.
Again, it's pretty straight forward, have a look at the [inline documentation](http://ggozad.com/strophe.plugins/docs/strophe.pubsub.html). A user can manage his subscription or getting all of them by using `subscribe`, `unsubscribe`, `getSubscriptions`.

So for instance,

```
var p = connection.PubSub.subscribe('/nodes/my_node')
    .done(function () { console.log('You are subscribed'); })
    .fail(function () { console.log('Ohoh, something went wrong'); });
```

will subscribe the connected user to the node `/nodes/my_node`

Comment: I'm trying to do it on the client side. Can I use Backbone.Collection and Backbone.Model to put the results into the Collection for example? But if so, it will try to sync it over http. How to overcome this problem? Or just use a View to display it? A short example in code would be great! I tried to do it yesterday the whole day without success. So a short code example will be really appreciated.

Comment: I updated with an example. No you should not use a "normal" model/collection, use the provided ones in Backbone.xmpp. If the user is subscribed, they will just sync automagically.

Comment: My problem is to get the subscriptions and display it and whenever the user wants to unsubscribe, then unsubscribe. So I get the subscriptions with p = XMPPConnection.PubSub.getSubscriptions();
p.done(function (subscriptions) {return subscriptions;}); p.fail(...); Is that right? Do I have to JSON.parse it? Then just put in the View and display it?

Comment: well getSubscriptions will return an array of the subscriptions including jids of the subscribers, subids etc. You do not need to JSON parse it, it's an array of object literals. Note you might not be allowed to do getSubscriptions, depending on your node setup.